# How to load image in textview?

Tags: android

I want to display image in textview,is it possible?anybody knows,please give sample code for me..
Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("abc");
    Drawable d = img.getDrawable();
    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    et.setText(ss);
```

Answer (score 0):

tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);

Comment: left/top/right/bottom = image drawables. Else you can supply the ResId (there is an overloaded function that accepts int)