# Textview image in android

Tags: android, textview

In my application i have to show an image in my text view. Also When i click 1st time 1 image should draw and clicking next time another image should be drawn.Is it possible to draw an image in textview?Please help me..

Comment: and why do u want to do that!!, You have image views to show images

Comment: To display image in textview

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699583/how-to-load-image-in-textview

Comment: Tell us why you need it with a TextView, so that if there are alternatives available they will be provided.

Comment: Actually b4 i displayed one string in that textview..So my thinking gone that way itself (i.e) whether is it possible to have a image in case of text..thats y...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a background image using the `android:background` attribute

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/image" />
```

Or programatically with the `setBackgroundDrawable()`or `setBackgroundResource()` methods:

```
textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
```

Comment: HI fiddler..Thanks its working..One more fiddler.In my app when oi clicking textview 2 automatically textview 1 image should disappear. is it possible?????

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question...could you explain a bit?

Comment: You can assign this to the Textview: android:clickable="true" to register touch events and add this too: android:onClick="textViewOnClick"

Then, you need to implement the method textViewOnClick on your activity like this:
public void textViewOnClick(View v){
  //logic to change background image on every click with
//textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
}

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
setCompoundDrawables(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom)
```

for the textView

Comment: You add compound drawables through the xml as weel: `           android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_close"
` for example

Answer (score 1):

You can take an array of Drawables, an an index for that:

```
TextView tv;
Drawable[] drbl = new Drawable[4];
int drblIndex = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    drbl[0] = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    drbl[1] = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img2);
    drbl[2] = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img3);
    drbl[3] = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.right_arrow);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tv.setBackgroundDrawable(drbl[drblIndex++]);
            if(drblIndex == drbl.length)
                drblIndex = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

Then you can set values of that array as I have done.

Then onClick you can move to next Index and can set new Drawable-Image to TextView.

When Index reaches to last value, set it to zero, simply.

Comment: Oops!!Ok will delete mine One.Dn't think that i have duplicated..our logic matched..i m happy that i am thinking like other humans..::))))

Answer (score 0):

Set `OnClickListener` on the TextView and in its `onClick()` method, use the following methods to set the images :

```
textview.setBackgroundDrawable();
```

or

```
textview.setBackgroundResource();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code, textview with image.

CharSequence dogstate = null ;
Html.fromHtml("" + " "
                                + "your text" + "
", featuregetter, null);

dogatstatus.append(dogstate);

private ImageGetter featuregetter = new ImageGetter() {

```
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {

        Log.i(" get drawable mathod ", "");
        Bitmap B = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.bone);
        BitmapDrawable BD = new BitmapDrawable(B);

        BD.setBounds(0, 0, B.getWidth(), B.getHeight());

        return BD;
    }
};
```